# How can I mock session when testing an action method that stores a key value pair to session storage using asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Please keep in mind am fairly new to mocking and testing. In my test method I have some code like so which mocks the controller:

```
        var azureReportControllerUnderTest = new AzureReportsController(mockIlogger.Object, mockPrismRepository.Object, mockReportRepository.Object);

        azureReportControllerUnderTest.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
        };

        azureReportControllerUnderTest.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, selectedTenantCookie);
        azureReportControllerUnderTest.HttpContext.Session.Set(handle, memoryStream.ToArray());
        azureReportControllerUnderTest.HttpContext.Session.Get(handle);
```

This is my action method where I create a guid and a byte array as a key value pair to store a file in session.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ResourcesCustomReports(DateTime? startingDate, DateTime? endingDate)
    {
        var selectedTenant = this.GetCurrentTenant();
        var fileName = $"resources_report_tenant_id_{selectedTenant}.xlsx";
        var workbook = this.reportsRepository.GetCustomDateResources(selectedTenant, startingDate, endingDate);
        string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook?.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            this.HttpContext.Session.Set(handle, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        return this.Json(new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = fileName });
    }
```

What I need is simply to be able to mock the session so I can pass the test. Currently though I am getting an error like this:
[image: error]

This is my assertion that I need to pass through:

```
 var result=azureReportControllerUnderTest.ResourcesCustomReports(to, from);
 Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```

Comment: `session has not been configured for this application or request`Have you configured session in startup.cs?You can try to refer to thr official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: It's already set up and the code it self works i.e storing and retrieving data. I need to mock the of cookie and session in the test. I solved it like this ->                              var mockedSession = new Mock<ISession>(); 
azureReportControllerUnderTest.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session = mockedSession.Object;